# Dynamical system in a square

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am considering a problem that is asking me to explore a deceptively simple dynamical system and discover some of surprising properties. I want to consider the motion of four particles A,B,C and D in the plane. The particles start at four random points in the plane. Each particle moves with unit speed. A moves towards B, B towards C, C towards D and D towards A. What happens (qualitatively), and how (quantitatively, in terms of, say, angles and log distances)?
I was wondering if somebody could give me some direction in terms of the the simplest case, when the starting positions form a square.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/18462?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: http://www.mrlsmath.com/geogebra/geogebra-materials/spiraling-squares-ants-problem/

Comment: Please avoid the tags [tag:undergraduate-research] and [tag:research]. We are trying to remove them.